# Can the word "attached" used as a noun?

Tags: meaning

I am confused about this word "attached" when I receive a letter begins like this: Dear XX, **attached** is a document for…… Here, the word "attached" is used somehow like a noun which means attachment, is that right?

Comment: attached is the attachment :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "attached is the receipt" an inverted sentence or reduced relative clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/321159/inverted-sentence-reduced-relative-clause)

Answer (score 2):

No, *attached* is an adjective adjected to the noun *document.* What
confuses you is the word order.  Your example is equivalent to

> .. a document for .. is attached.

Changing the word order does not change the role of *attached.*

Comment: Ach so! Vielen Dank! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *Dear XX, a document for x is attached.*
>
> [2] *Dear XX, attached is a document for x*

No: "attached" is not a noun but an adjective.

This is about subject-dependent inversion:

[1] is the basic version, but [2] combines the preposing of the AdjP "attached" and postposing of the subject NP "a document for x".

Comment: What is an AdjP?  (Do English words admit of this typographical form?)  What is an NP?

Comment: @Toothrot AdjP=adjective phrase, NP=noun phrase. These are fairly standard abbreviations throughout the world of grammar. The others are VP (verb phrase), DP (determinative phrase), AdvP (adverb phrase), PP (preposition phrase).